# Isotope Images stacked in ie9 NOT Safari/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm hoping this is an easy fix. My website http://www.solcroft.co.uk/portfolio/ renders perfectly using jquery isotope filtering in Safari/Firefox/Chrome but not in IE9. All the images seem to stack up over each other. Any ideas? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any isotope rendering on the link you sent. But going to the portfolio and client pages, the isotope grids look just fine in IE 9 from here.

Comment: Thats really odd. Have tried the site from this end and the css is all over the place only on IE browsers. What an earth is going on?! Works perfectly on all others. Help. Microsoft what are you doing?

Comment: Maybe it's cached? Looks good here, Isotope filtering works, no visual errors.